# Provider side maching not work on request body

Tags: pact, pact-jvm

Provider side matching is not working  if I add any thing or rename  or remove any field in request body of provider which is not same as contract then its not failing.

Eg inside contract file request body contain name field and the same field if I remove or rename in request body of provider (not in response) only in request then pact is not validating that.

I want to confirm at provider side will the matching work on request body?

I can see matching rule for request body in pact file but its seems like not functioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding new fields into a provider response that is not required by a Pact contract is simply ignored.

Why is this the case? Pact follows [Postel's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle). *Unexpected elements in a response should not cause issues for a consumer.* Other consumers may have different but overlapping needs, so failing a provider build on these grounds is problematic.

From our [docs](https://docs.pact.io/getting_started/matching/gotchas/#pact-follows-postels-law), what this translates to:

> Be conservative in what you send - when the mock server in the consumer project compares the actual request with the expected request, the actual request body is not allowed to contain fields that are not defined in the expected request body. We don't want the situation where our real consumer is "leaking" data that we don't know about.

> Be liberal in what you accept - when verifying a pact in the provider project, the response body and headers may contain fields that were not defined in the expectations, on the assumption that any extra field will be ignored by your consumer. This allows a provider to evolve without breaking existing consumers (unlike the bad old WSDL days).

To your second point:

> I want to confirm at provider side will the matching work on request body?

It sounds like it is working. It's correctly identifying breaking changes if you change the datatype, or have an unexpected response code.

If you rename a field that is *required by a consumer*, then that sounds like a bug (a fatal one in terms of Pact features, so I'm skeptical).

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. The problem I am facing with only request body not with response you are right if we change any thing in response body then  contract fail and it is working expected. However the problem is with request body at provider end. I have edit my question. If we change data type string to int  it fails because it trying to send string value to int field that is something java failure. If we change int to double then wont fail because int value can be pass in double. So this is something java failure not by pact.

Comment: Like I side if consumer send name field in contract and if same I change to firstName in provider project(request body not in response) then it dont validating. I can see matching rule in pact file for request body as well but its not functioning

Comment: Matching rules are only applied in the consumer test, not the provider side. I'm afraid I don't follow your question though. Could you perhaps please update your question to show the actual test on the consumer side, the response on the provider side and the contract. A gist / example project to share might be more helpful though.